# EGit unstaged files will not go away

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have 3 files in the Unstaged Changes box that I cannot make go away.  I've reset hard, replace with HEAD version, assumed unchanged: nothing makes these files go away and when I do compares on them with another branch or the HEAD revision, there are no differences.  Mystified, so say the least.  Also this morning my local Remotes for fetch/pull in Eclipse just disappeared and I had to rebuild them.  These events may be related, but I'm not sure.  Is there a repair action I can do for EGit?  This shouldn't be a line-ending problem like what I've found in my research.  I've lost a fair amount of productivity today on this.

I think I've suffered some kind of corruption of the IDE.  Can't prove it; it's just a hunch.  Here's my relevant info:

Windows 10

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800

EGit 5.1.0.201809111528-r

Comment: The _Git Stagging_ view has a _Refresh_ button in case you make changes to the Git repository outside of Eclipse (e.g. via the Git command line tool). If this does not fix your issue, please tell which EGit version do you use and if these are only whitespace (e.g. line breaks) changes.

Comment: Tried the refresh button.  No effect.  Something will pop up.  I'm continuing my research.

Comment: You are some releases behind with Eclipse and EGit. Can you reproduce the issue in the current version?